# Angular 13 Interceptor does not seem to catch a 403 error

Tags: angular, .net-6.0

Running a .NET 6 API, the Angular 13 application does not seem to intercept a 403 error. The 401 error works fine, however, the 403 error seems to not fall into the (err: any) block but it does show up in the tap(() => { } section.

```
import { Injectable } from "@angular/core";
import { HttpInterceptor, HttpRequest, HttpHandler, HttpErrorResponse } from "@angular/common/http";
import { AuthService } from "../services/auth.service";
import { tap } from 'rxjs/operators';
import { Router } from '@angular/router';

@Injectable()

export class AuthInterceptor implements HttpInterceptor {

    constructor(private auth: AuthService, private router: Router) { }

    intercept(req: HttpRequest<any>, next: HttpHandler) {
        const authToken = this.auth.getToken();
        if (authToken != null) {
            req = req.clone({
                setHeaders: {
                    Authorization: "Bearer " + authToken
                }
            });
        }

        return next.handle(req).pipe(tap(() => { },
            (err: any) => {
                if (err instanceof HttpErrorResponse) {
                    if (err.status === 401 || err.status === 403) {
                        this.auth.logout();
                        this.router.navigate(['login']);
                    }
                }
            }));
    }
}
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

I restarted the angular server via "ng s" and now it seems to be working.
Looks like my bad.